# Can a NuGet package built with a newer version of c# be used in a project using an older version of c#?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard, csproj

If I build and publish a NuGet package with a Language Version of 9, can I install and reference the NuGet package in a project using a lower Language version (for example c# 7)?

NuGet Package .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>9</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Consuming library .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? (P.S. I'd expect so yes because when you build a C# program it's compiled down to IL. So the raw C# never gets anywhere near the target project. AFAIK the C# version only determines what language features you can use when coding and what compiler version you need. What it compiles _to_ depends on the target .NET Framework. Bear in mind, when you install a nuget package (or any reference any other .NET DLL), you don't even know if it was originally written in C# or another language - that's one of the nice things about .NET)

Comment: Officially, the language version is now tied to the target framework version (although you can override this with `LangVersion`, officially you're in unsupported terratory). In practice, so long as you're not using C# features which rely on newer target frameworks (you'd need jump through hoops and use polyfills to do this, such as defining `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit` to use init-only properties) you'll be fine.

Comment: @canton7 even things like init-only accessors gives consideration to older compilers; that's *why* it uses mod-req; the caveat being that you won't be able to use the property at all, *even in* an initializer. Things that don't touch that property should be fine, though.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yep, the point I was trying to make is that if you're using polyfills in order to define types/methods using features introduced by newer compilers, don't necessarily expect older compilers to be able to use those types/methods in the same way that newer compilers can.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible.

So after a suggestion from [@ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) I tried to do this myself locally.

It took me about 30 minutes to build a `.netstandard2.0` project with a reference to `IAsyncEnumerable` with the *Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 5.0.0* NuGet package as it doesn't natively get included in `.netstardard2.0`.

After packing up a NuGet locally, I included it into a Console Application using `.netcore2.1` and called a method that used the `IAsyncEnumerable`.   It worked!